# Using JSON response in CFIF

Tags: json, ajax, coldfusion

Is it possible to use response.DATA[i][j] in a CFIF statement.

```
chkUsernameUnique = function(theUsername){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/book.cfc",
    data: {method: "testFunction", datum: $('#date').val(), returnFormat: "JSON"},
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response) {
    var str = '<table><tr>';
    var i;
    var j;

    //loop over each column name for headers
    for (i = 0; i < response.COLUMNS.length; i++) {
          str += '<th>' + response.COLUMNS[i] + '</th>';
      }

    str += '</tr>';

    //loop over each row
    for (i = 0; i < response.DATA.length; i++) {
      str += '<tr>';
      //loop over each column
      for (j = 0; j < response.DATA[i].length; j++) {
          str += '<td>' + response.DATA[i][j] + '</td>';
      }
      str += '</tr>';
    }
    str += '</table>';

    $('#debugDiv').html(str);
},
error: function(ErrorMsg) {
   console.log('Error');
}
});
}
```

What I want to do is something like:

`<cfif response.DATA[i][j] is 3> str += '<td>test</td>';</cfif>`

This returns the following error message: variable [RESPONSE] doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

The `response` variable is the server response for your AJAX request and you are working with it on clientside. Thus you are still in the realm of JavaScript:

```
if (response.DATA[i][j] == 3) { str += '<td>test</td>'; }
```

ColdFusion (i.e. `<cfif>`) is executed on serverside, thus cannot be used to evaluate data during runtime (after the browser requested an URI).